# mySQL - show first and last log from each day

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql  table with colums: id(primary), name(varchar), TIME(timestamp)

```
ID , NAME , TIME
```

i want to get just first and last log for each day

```
example if i have data like this 

1,name,2018-20-21 12:35:00
2,name,2018-20-21 13:38:00
3,name,2018-20-21 14:25:00
4,name,2018-20-21 15:39:00
5,name,2018-20-21 21:48:00 
6,name,2018-20-22 13:25:00
7,name,2018-20-22 14:39:00
8,name,2018-20-22 19:48:00
```

i want to get in just this

```
 1,name,2018-20-21 12:35:00
 5,name,2018-20-21 21:48:00 

 6,name,2018-20-22 13:25:00
 8,name,2018-20-22 19:48:00
```

Comment: what is your mysql version ?

Comment: why that is needed

Comment: in MySQL version > 8.0, you could use window functions to get these results in a neater fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

SELECT name, MAX(time), MIN(time) FROM Table GROUP BY DATE(time);

Answer (score 0):

You could use the union for  the min and the max time  group by date 
and join this with your table

```
    select * from my_table 
    inner join  (     
    select * from (
     select   min(time) my_time 
     from my_table  
     group by date(time)
     union 
     select   max(time)
     from my_table  
     group by date(time)
    ) t on t.my_time = my_table.time
    order by  my_table.time
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on t.my_time = my_table.time
    order by  my_table.time LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: there is not limit 0,25  in my query  ..so you should use my code  ..  and test the code without others  code added ..  +

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT id, tmp.name, tmp.time FROM
(SELECT id, name, min(time) as time FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE(time)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, name, max(time) as time FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE(time)) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting the min and max for each day, since you want the entire line, a join is needed
and to filter out the actual min and max day, a aub query is needed

```
SELECT id, name, time
FROM
(

SELECT t2.*, MIN(DATE(t.time)) As min0 MAX(DATE(t.time)) As max0
FROM
 table t
 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t.id = t2.id
GROUP BY
 DATE (t.time), 
min0, 
max0
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    l.id,l.name,l.time
FROM
    log l
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        max(time) as maxTime
    FROM
        log
    GROUP BY date(time)) l1 ON l.time = l1.maxTime
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        min(time) as minTime
    FROM
        log
    GROUP BY date(time)) l2 ON l.time = l2.minTime
WHERE
    (maxTime IS NOT NULL
        OR minTime IS NOT NUll);
SELECT * from stack.log;
```